# How do I manually boot from the grub prompt after do-release-upgrade?

Tags: server, boot, grub2, bootloader, kvm-virtualization

I read a couple of other questions on this topic and they both pointed to the Grub2 community documentation and installing grub configs from an install disk.  I had some trouble with the documentation, so here's where I am.  This may be complete PEBKAC.

I have two guests sitting on an Ubuntu 10.04 server virtualized under KVM, both were initially running 10.04.  I used "do-release-upgrade" to update to 10.10 without a hitch on both boxes, rebooted, and then ran "do-release-upgrade" to update to 11.04 on both boxes.  In my haste, I ignored the errors about missing grub configurations.  When I restarted the guests, naturally I'm presented with a grub prompt.  Issuing "boot" yields "error: no loaded kernel".

Here's ls output for the root partition:

[image: grub prompt ls output]

When following the manual boot guide, I can't get the options straight either using "SS928-root" or "hda0,1" as the root filesystem.  Most everything gives the "file not found" error.

Issuing "ls" on both of those filesystems show several options for vmlinuz and initrd.img.  These guests are using LVM if that helps any.

**EDIT**

I've gotten a little bit further.  The following command sequence:

[image: semi-successful boot]

Yields the following screen (after scrolling through quite a bit of text):

[image: BusyBox Shell]

Comment: Your post helped me recover my boot after nasty windows 10 "update". Linux even recovered after hybernation with entire session intact. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After looking at jdehaan's post, I checked out a machine with a similiar configuration. Going off another box's grub.cfg, I used the following commands to get this thing to boot:

```
recordfail
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,1)'
linux /vmlinuz-2.6.32-server root=/dev/mapper/SS928-root ro quiet
initrd /initrd.img-2.6.32.30-server
boot
```

I suppose the next step is figuring out how to replace the grub.cfg on this machine now.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and could solve the problem by specifying

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz.... root=/dev/sda1
```

So **/dev/sda1** (or what will match on your system) instead of the SS... The rest of your posts was kept alike during my tries.

Comment: I suppose that, in theory, because this thing is running LVM that should be /dev/mapper/SS928-root.  That's definitely not working in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a working grub config somewhere, `ls` at the root level lists partitions, and `configfile (boot device)/path/to/grub.config` lets you boot your grub config.